# how to change the fields added to blog in drupal 7 where I want

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am developing a website using drupal 7. I use blog module which comes as a core module in drupal 7. in the blog post I have not only added text but also a slideshow to the blog.
problem comes when I try to arrange the blog content.

I wanted to show some text message after the slideshow on left-hand side.
Normally, in drupal they render text and then slideshow(default). but I want to change it as I mentioned above.

Is there any module to handle this or can I do it another alternative way?

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [DS](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to customize node layouts

Answer (score 0):

The way that will give you the most flexibility for customization would be to actually edit the template files themselves and place the individual fields' output exactly where you want in the HTML.

Check out the documentation for [overriding and editing theme files](http://drupal.org/node/1089656), and this post for how to render [individual fields into template files](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).